# Are there scripts and stats that can provide a measure of the rate of "abandonment" of posts?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

Is there a script and maybe also old statistics on the response rate of OPs to reviewer comments? In other words, when I leave a comment below a question seeking additional information or requesting changes, I know from experience that a substantial fraction of the time the OP will not respond (and often none of the other commenters either). This is of course a source of frustration and a point worth evaluating when one dwells into arguments surrounding "effort" as grounds for closure.

So: are there stats (and scripts one could reuse) that can provide a measure of the rate of "abandonment" of posts, that is, of OPs going silent?

I am sure this has been asked before (so I have to apologize that I didn't put enough effort into my search to find the dupe(s) :-) ). I did find [this post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/570/what-should-we-do-about-homework-problems) which comes close.

Comment: One can compare the date and time the question's been posted with these in *Last seen* field in user's profile. If these are identical or close, there is little chance of getting feedback. A person that is interested in getting their problem solved would stay for a while waiting for the answers or comments. On top of that, if there is "Unregistered" next to user's profile name, the chances OP ever visits the site again are tiny, and OP may pop up using a different account after a week or two claiming authorship of the post and wondering why it got closed.

Comment: Thanks @andselisk that's a good method which I've used once or twice in the past but seemed to have forgotten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a SEDE query to give some insights in this. Do note that if questions remain unanswered and don't get a score > 0 they will fall victim to the [roomba](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) eventually. As SEDE doesn't have much useful data on deleted posts for your specific stats request the real numbers might be higher.

```
total posts total questions total answers 
----------- --------------- ------------- 
76288       34792           41496         

# with comments, not OP # questions # closed # answers OP did edit post 
----------------------- ----------- -------- --------- ---------------- 
1671                    834         128      837       1331
```

Here is the [full query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/1258967):

```sql
;with PostsEditedByOp as 
(
 select distinct postid
 from posthistory ph
 inner join posts p on p.id  = ph.postid
 where posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6,7,8,9)  -- edits / rollback
 and (owneruserid = ph.userid)
)

select (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid in (1,2)) [total posts]
     , (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid = 1) [total questions]
     , (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid = 2) [total answers]
     , count(*) [# with comments, not OP] 
     , sum(case posttypeid when 1 then 1 else 0 end) [# questions]
     , sum(case when posttypeid = 1 and closeddate is not null then 1 else 0 end) [# closed]
     , sum(case posttypeid when 2 then 1 else 0 end) [# answers]
     , sum(case when pe.postid is null then 1 else 0 end) [OP did edit post]
from posts p
left outer join PostsEditedByOp pe on pe.postid = p.id
where posttypeid in (1,2)
and commentcount > 0
and not exists 
  ( select *
    from
    comments c 
    where c.postid = p.id
    and c.userid <> p.owneruserid)
```

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Never forget that [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) created the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).